# I want to set preauthorizeApiKey in swagger-ui-react application auto authorized

Tags: reactjs, authorization, swagger-ui

I have below code where I have set preauthorizeApiKey and it's working fine and calls to APIs is also working. APIs need header "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx". I had key stored in react store and reading using getToken().

```
import React from 'react';
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-react';
import swaggerSpec from '../../swagger.json';
import { getToken } from '../../api/utils'

export const complete=function(swaggerUi)
{
  let token = getToken();
  swaggerUi.preauthorizeApiKey('bearerAuth',  token.Token);
}

const ApiDocs = () => {
  return <SwaggerUI spec={swaggerSpec} onComplete={(swaggerUi) => complete(swaggerUi)} />
};

export default ApiDocs;
```

Below is my route configuration:

```
<Route path="/api-docs" component={ApiDocs} />
```

I don't need to click on Authorize button on swagger UI screen and it is auto Authorized. Just wanted to share for any comment/suggestion/improvement.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The **onComplete** props should be a function. Please see the document [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react?activeTab=readme).

```
import React from "react";
import SwaggerUI from "swagger-ui-react";
import swaggerSpec from "../../swagger.json";
import { getToken } from "../../api/utils";

export const complete = function (swaggerUi) {
  const token = getToken();
  swaggerUi.preauthorizeApiKey("bearerAuth", token.Token);
};

const ApiDocs = () => {
  return <SwaggerUI spec={swaggerSpec} onComplete={complete} />;
};

export default ApiDocs;
```

Answer (score 1):

For people still unable in need to solve this issue

**requestInterceptor** function should be used to manipulate the Request and add the authorization needed

```
import React from "react";
import SwaggerUI from "swagger-ui-react";
import swaggerSpec from "../../swagger.json";
import { getToken } from "../../api/utils";



const ApiDocs = () => {
 const requestInterceptor = function (req: { [k: string]: any }) {
  const token = getToken();
  req.headers = { ...req.headers, bearerAuth: token  };
  return req;
 };
  
 return <SwaggerUI spec={swaggerSpec} requestInterceptor={requestInterceptor} />;
};

export default ApiDocs;
```